# What types of information-transmitting cables have the least ping time?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

What types of information-transmittimg cables (including receiving and transmitting devices) have the least ping time (signal speed), whether optical, electric, other? Will superconducting cables reduce ping time?

Answer (score 0):

An empty (essentially air-filled) coaxial cable or a pair of wires have propagation velocity equal to that of $c$ the vacuum velocity of light, nothing moves faster than that be it superconducting or otherwise.